# ReactJS Image Upload via MultiPart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multipart

We are trying to upload images to a NodeJS server that uses expressjs/multer to parse `multipart/form-data` input. Unfortunately, we encounter a TypeError like so:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
     at /var/www/app/services/media/multer.js:41:31
     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:52:37)
     at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:590:18)
     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15)
     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.
```

After looking into it, we figured out that this backend error meant that multer.js didn't add a `file` field unto the `req`, thus resulting in a `req.file.path ===> TypeError` in a later manipulation of the image.

Using Wireshark to sniff the packet, we found out that the method we employed to upload was sending a *path* rather than a file's content.

Here's the ReactJS code (using superagent):

```
selectPhotoTapped() {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({
        title: 'Select Image'
    }, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {


            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                request
                    .put(Environment.BASE_URL + '/media/img/')
                    .attach('upload', response.path, response.fileName)
                    .field('usertype', 'Barber')
                    .field('name', 'profilePic')
                    .field('description', 'Holla')
                    .field('type', 'test:barber:haircut')
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(res);
                        }
                    });
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                alert("HERE");
                response.json();
            }).then((responseData) => {
                alert("Succes " + responseData)
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert("ERROR " + error)
                console.log(error);
            });

        }
    });

}
```

and here is our backend multer code:

```
var storage = Multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../../', config.media.img),
    filename: generate_filename
  });
  var multer = Multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024,
    fileFilter: filter
  });
router.put('/media/img/', auth.authenticate, multer.single('upload'), media.img.put);
```

So the question is: Why does superagent send only the path when we use the  `attach` method? We have tested the exact same superagent code in our mocha test of the backend and everything turned out fine. So why the difference between React and Node?

If you want more information, you can check this print of the request [before](http://pastebin.com/w0uieWBS) and [after](http://pastebin.com/da0NXKrc) the multer middleware parsed it.

Comment: I see `.attach('upload', response.path, response.fileName)` is response undefined?

Comment: The response went directly to the catch since the server crashed and unexpectedly killed the keep-alive TCP connection. Let me modify the code to prevent the crash and I'll come back to you

Comment: I would recommend ANY response you get from the server you should probably have it handle any invalid data like that. So for instance you could use lodash for this simply. `.attach('upload', _.get(response, 'path'), _.get(response, 'fileName'))` the `get` method takes a path to look for on a variable, if any part of that path doesn't exist or is the wrong data type it will return undefined so that way you dont have breaking javascript code that could potentially break your application

Comment: Oh, the path error is actually on the server side. I should have made that more clear.
Also, the response object you point at is the following: `{
  data: "some base64 string"
  fileName: "Screenshot_20170106-161518.png"
  fileSize: 1569026
  height: 2560
  isVertical: true
  path: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20170106-161518.png"
  type: "image/png"
  uri: "content://com.atomicadd.fotos.media/photo/102032"
  width: 1440
}`

Comment: Yea but when the server fails or doesn't return something your javascript will fail because response is undefined. just saying you should be ready to handle that use case on the UI side regardless of if the server is working or not :)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the heads up. Any idea regarding the question?